# fine-tune the model from TensorFlow Hub

Tags: tensorflow-hub, fine-tuning

I have used this code from the TensorFlow website:

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub
```

I have to implement the entire code without any problem, but I am wondering how can I Fine-Tune it since I cannot access the:

```
 base_model.trainable or base_model.layers
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `trainable=True` in

```
feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(
    feature_extractor_model,
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
    trainable=False)
```

Though it is better to keep the base layers frozen at least during the initial rounds of training.

Comment: but how can i frozen other layers?